# WaitForSingleObjects with timeout = 0

Tags: windows, winapi

Does `WaitForSingleObject()` with timeout = 0 ms result in thread context switch immediately and the thread to loose its remaining timeslice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation says otherwise. [MSDN: WatiForSingleObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687032.aspx):

> If dwMilliseconds is zero, the function does not enter a wait state if the object is not signaled; it always returns immediately.

Answer (score 2):

If the handle is signaled it does not enter a waite state ever.  And if the dwMilliseconds parameter is 0 it will not enter the wait state even if it is not signaled.

Regarding its second param: dwMilliseconds  [MSDN says the following](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687032.aspx):

> ...
>   if dwMilliseconds is zero,
>   the function does not enter a wait
>   state if the object is not signaled;
>   it always returns immediately...